# Oauth 2.0 Azure en programa de consola

Tags: azure, autenticación

necesito obtener la autorización, token y refresh token desde una aplicación de consola. Necesito que me aparezca la pantalla de logarme en la aplicación de consola. Sé que es posible pero no soy capaz

```
   string url = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id={*clientID*}&response_type=code";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

¿Podéis ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

Lo estás abordando de la manera incorrecta, así no te funcionará.

Lo que debes hacer en resumen es:

1. Regstrar tu app en el Azure active directory
2. Usar los secretos de la App para iniciar el flujo de autenticacion
3. cuando eso este listo puedes tomar diversas aproximaciones una de ellas\
4. generar una URL para autenticacion, la cual el usuario o tu app puede hacer para lanzar el browser
5. una vez en el browser el usuario recibe un codigo de verificacion
6. el usuario ingresa el codigo en la consola, debes usar tu programa para recibir ese codigo
7. con ese codigo terminas el flujo de autenticacion

No es tan trivial de hacer pero tampoco es tan complejo, pero si es la primera vez que te enfrentas con este tema puede ser bastante engorroso.

Más info acá auque está con la primera version de Azure Active Directory, pero el flujo sigue siendo basicamente el mismo aunque la interfaz haya cambiado.

http://simonjaeger.com/understand-the-microsoft-graph-with-a-console-app/

Tambien te recomiendo usar [ADAL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries).